# ReactJS Accessing Props of Rendered Component

Tags: reactjs, state

I am building a component that will be used for step-through processes such as :

[image]

This `Workflow` component takes an `array` of 'steps' as a prop and then it does the rest. Here is how it is being called in the image above :

```js
let steps = [
{
    display: "Sign Up Form",
    component: SignupForm
},
{
   display: "Verify Phone",
   component: VerifyPhone
},
{
   display: "Use Case Survey",
   component: UseCase
},
{
   display: "User Profile",
   component: UserProfile
},
];

return (
    <Workflow
        steps={steps}
    />
);
```

The `component` field points to the component to be rendered in that step. For example the `SignupForm` component looks like this :

```js
export default class SignupForm extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="page-header">
                    <h1>New User Sign Up Form</h1>
                    <p>Something here...</p>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address..." />
                    <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that in each step there needs to be a `Next` button to validate the information in that step and move to the next. I was going to just put that button inside the component of each step, but that makes it less user-friendly. When a user clicks 'Next', and everything is valid, that step should be collapsed and the next step should open up. However this means that my `Workflow` component needs to render this button.

So, I need my `Workflow` component to call the method of each step component to validate the information in the step and return a promise letting it know if it passed or failed (with any error message). How do I need to call this method? Here is where the `Workflow` component renders all the steps 
 as `<step.component {...this.props} />`:

```js
{
    this.state.steps.map((step, key) => {
        return (
            ...
                <Collapse isOpen={!step.collapsed}>
                    <step.component {...this.props} />
                    <Button color="primary"
                            onClick={() => this.validate(key)}>Next</Button>
                    <div className="invalid-value">
                        {step.error}
                    </div>
                </Collapse>
            ...
        );
    })
}
```

That renders the next button, as well as the onClick handler `validate()`:

```js
    validate(i) {
        let steps = _.cloneDeep(this.state.steps);
        let step = steps[i];

        step.component.handleNext().then(function () {
            ...
        }).catch((err) => {
            ...
        });
    }
```

Ideally, `step.component.validate()` would call the `validate` method inside that component that has already been rendered:

```js
export default class SignupForm extends React.Component {
    ....

    validate() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve();
        })
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

.. which would have access to the state of that component. But, thats not how it works. How can I get this to work? I read a little about forwarding refs, but not exactly sure how that works. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to apply the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) by making your form a Context [Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#provider) and making it provide a "register" function for registering [Consumers](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consumer). Your consumers would be each of the XXXForm components. They would all implement the same `validate` API, so the wrapping form could assume it could call `validate` on any of its registered components.

It could look something like the following:

```js
const WorkflowContext = React.createContext({
  deregisterForm() {},
  registerForm() {},
});

export default class Workflow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      forms: [],
    };
  }

  deregisterForm = (form) => {
    this.setState({
      forms: this.state.forms.slice().splice(
        this.state.forms.indexOf(forms), 1)
    });
  };

  registerForm = (form) => {
    this.setState({ forms: [ ...this.state.forms, form ] })
  };

  validate = () => {
    const validationPromises = this.state.forms.reduce(
      (promises, formComponent) => [...promises, formComponent.validate()]);
    Promise.all(validationPromises)
      .then(() => {
        // All validation Promises resolved, now do some work.
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // Some validation Promises rejected. Handle error.
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <WorkflowContext.Provider
        value={{
          deregisterForm: this.deregisterForm,
          registerForm: this.registerForm,
        }}>
        {/* Render all of the steps like in your pasted code */}
        <button onClick={this.validate}>Next</button
      </WorkflowContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

// Higher-order component for giving access to the Workflow's context
export function withWorkflow(Component) {
  return function ManagedForm(props) {
    return (
      <WorkflowContext.Consumer>
        {options =>
          <Component
            {...props}
            deregisterForm={options.deregisterForm}
            registerForm={options.registerForm}
          />
        }
      </WorkflowContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

`SignupForm` and any other form that needs to implement validation:

```js
import { withWorkflow } from './Workflow';

class SignupForm extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.registerForm(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.deregisterForm(this);
  }

  validate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve();
    })
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

// Register each of your forms with the Workflow by using the
// higher-order component created above.
export default withWorkflow(SignupForm);
```

This pattern I originally found applied to React when reading [react-form's](https://github.com/react-tools/react-form) source, and it works nicely.

Comment: Is the `FormManager` your implementation of my `Workflow` component? Or is it the implementation of the Workflow component?

Comment: @JonStevens Sorry about that, I realized I didn't use your original component names. I just re-wrote the code using your names.

Comment: No worries. How would the implementation of the `Workflow` component look? I'm getting an error in the component I'm trying to use the `Workflow` component. Where it's being used: 

```return (
            <Workflow
                steps={steps}
            />
        );```

.. I'm getting an error that says: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: It's in the first code snippet in my question above. That's a little easier to read.

Comment: Oh my code is also missing a `return` in the `render` method, haha. Sorry, I didn't actually run this code...

Comment: I've actually got that too and still the same error haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171014/discussion-between-ross-allen-and-jon-stevens).